# Noir - unable to resolve symbol html5 in this context

Tags: clojure, noir, hiccup

I am trying to use noir and am following the tutorial that is given at the default tutorial and am using this code

```
(defpage "/my-page" []
  (html5
    [:h1 "This is my first page!"]))
```

However, clojure throws up an error and refuses to work.

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more detail than that? Do you have an stacktrace?

Comment: Could you include your project.clj and the (ns package.example ...) declaration from the top of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your namespace declaration look like?

Chances are you're not `use`ing `defpage` and `html5`.

`defpage` is in the `noir.core` namespace and `html5` is either in the `hiccup.page-helpers` (hiccup version < 1) or `hiccup.page` (hiccup version >= 1) namespace.

If you used the noir template, there's a decent chance these were already included.